# PgRouting queries too slow

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, routing, osm2po, dijkstra

I'm writing a function that returns routes using PgRouting (v.2.6)
The main problem I'm having is that I cant get the time less than 1 second per query.

The main query I need is get **time, length, and the line**, so I don't need all the returning rows but a sum() of them.

I have this query:

```
SELECT  sum(rutanodos.cost*60) as sum_cost_minutes, sum(routing.calles_2po_4pgr.km) as sum_km,  
       round((st_length(st_union(st_transform(geom_way, 4258)))*100)::numeric, 3) as distancia_linea_km, st_asEWKT(st_union(geom_way)) as geom_json   
   FROM pgr_dijkstra(                           
  'SELECT id as id, source source, target target, cost, reverse_cost FROM routing.es_2po_4pgr   
   WHERE geom_way && ST_Expand(   
        (SELECT ST_Collect(the_geom) FROM routing.es_2po_4pgr_vertices_pgr WHERE id IN (38785, 744540)),0.01)',                                   
         38785, 744540, false, false) as rutanodos            
             join routing.es_2po_4pgr on routing.es_2po_4pgr.id = id2
```

In which:

- I obtain the route with pg_dijkstra() from a node to a node.
- I join the nodes with the line.
- Finally I group the list to get: SUM of costs, SUM of length, union of the geometry in EWKT.

And returns (in 1.1 second):

- sum of cost minutes:345.276354
- sum of Km: 643.367627099999
- line length: 729.228 (to see the difference with returned km)
- EWKT line geom: "SRID=4326;MULTILINESTRING((-1.7734135 42.2439494,-1.7732242 42.2408917),(-1.773393 42.2445657,-..."

After `explain` command:

```
- "Aggregate  (cost=8224.76..8226.67 rows=1 width=80)"
- "  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.68..8209.75 rows=1000 width=130)"
- "        ->  Function Scan on pgr_dijkstra rutanodos  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=12)"
- "        ->  Index Scan using calles_2po_4pgr_pk on calles_2po_4pgr  (cost=0.43..8.20 rows=1 width=126)"
- "              Index Cond: (id = rutanodos.id2)"
```

This works properly and with I get all the results that I need, but, as I said, it takes more than a second.

I've read some advices to optimize, but still can't get better time. For example.

- I've created indexes in source, target, geom and a primary key.
- Vacuum and cluster on index.
- Created bounding box for passing only a part of the network instead of all the nodes.
- My data comes from osm2po, with topology created.

I've read a lot of posts about, and I've seen that people can get times of 50ms, but the fastest time I can get is about a second.

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Anyone knows any other tip or recommendation to get better times?

Comment: can you add an explain for the query to the question

Comment: Query explained as @IanTurton suggested.

Comment: I meant what is the result of running `explain select sum(......`

Comment: Ok sorry, edited again :)

Comment: no, it is a special SQL command that will show us how the database engine processes the query, add `explain` to the start of your query and run it again. You should get result like `"Seq Scan on roadnode  (cost=0.00..4609.81 rows=119681 width=222)"` but longer

Comment: ouch. I didn't know this command. Sorry.

Comment: well, you are including quite a few rather costly spatial functions in your query, including `ST_Union` and `ST_Transform`, along with your aggregate functions. considering the length of your returned path (thus assuming a moderate amount of edges) I`d say 1.1 sec is rather quick!?

Comment: Where did you find posts, that claim to get responses in 50ms? How big is your data? If you have a larger dataset, then 1 second isn't necessarily bad.

Comment: The bottleneck is the Dijkstra algorithm. Significantly faster calculations are in my experience only possible with other algorithms (e.g. contraction hierarchies).